# How can I get rid of /etc/../run?

Tags: filesystem

For some reason (most probably happened during an upgrade more than one year ago), my system has a directory called `/etc/../run` (strange, right?).  It is empty but I cannot remove it:

```
$ ls /etc/../run
$ sudo rmdir /etc/../run
rmdir: échec de suppression de «/etc/../run»: Périphérique ou ressource occupé
$ ls -iald /etc/../run
393217 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 sep  6 19:18 /etc/../run
$ ls -iald /run
9221 drwxr-xr-x 31 root root 1060 sep 25 22:55 /run
$ ls -d /etc/../run | od -ha
0000000    652f    6374    2e2f    2f2e    7572    0a6e
          /   e   t   c   /   .   .   /   r   u   n  nl
0000014
$ ls -d /run | od -ha
0000000    722f    6e75    000a
          /   r   u   n  nl
0000005
$ ls -al /etc
total 1524
drwxr-xr-x 166 root     root      12288 sep 24 19:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root     root       4096 sep  6 19:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root       4096 aoû 25 20:03 acpi
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       2981 avr 23  2012 adduser.conf
...
$`
```

As I suspect this is the cause of some troubles, I would like to suppress it.  How?

Comment: try to post `ls -lad /etc/../run`. This should be really `/run`, but it's quite strange that's empty... Are you sure these are really to dots and not some different (unicode) char?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your comment.  Also added the result of `$ ls -lad /run`

Comment: This is really strange. This `..` directory is not what it seems. What is the result of `ls -al /etc` (trim it down to show just `.`, `..` and a few files) and `ls /etc/../run | od -ha` ? (Rationale: trying to see if the ".." is a fake).

Comment: I edited the question to give those results.

Comment: There is really something pesky here; even `od` acts strange. The ASCII code of `..` should be 0x2f 0x2f, see: `ls -d /etc/../run | od -ha` returns: `0000000    652f    6374    2e2f    2f2e    7572    0a6e`
`/   e   t   c   /   .   .   /   r   u   n  nl` (on two lines). I would recommend a shutdown followed by a fsck of the filesystem.

Comment: I see a difference between your two posts: in the last one, you use the '-d' switch, not in the first (the one I used).  Should I try with that switch?

Comment: Yes, try it. Still, `/etc/../run` and `/run` should be the same dir. Something really strange is happening if not; either one `..` is not really a dot-dot, or the filesystem is corrupted. I myself would backup, reboot and fsck the filesystem.

Comment: I edited again the answer replacing the commands `ls -ald` by `ls -iald` + the result of od, similar to what you say.  Now I will reboot the system and run fsck.

Comment: Done with fsck with no errors reported.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas now...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you quite literally have a directory named `..` in `/etc`, no, that directory is not in `/etc`. `..` refers to the parent directory of the current directory, (like `.` refers to itself) and exist for every directory:

```
$ ls -al /
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Jun  1  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 122 Jul 14 05:33 ..
```

So `/etc/../` actually refers to `/`, and `/etc/../run` refers to `/run`, which is **a very important folder**. Do NOT delete it.

Some configuration files, most notably `resolv.conf` maybe symbolic links to files in `/run`, but that is absolutely normal:

```
$ ls /etc/resolv.conf -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 23 17:54 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This is what I thought as well but I guess I have a directory named `..`.  You are right as well about the DNS symbolink link: this is where I started my investigation.  That led my to create the following link: `$ ls /etc/resolv.conf -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 sep  6 19:36 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.  Please note the absence of the two dots.  If I create the original link (with the dots), I have no DNS resolution. BTW thank you for editing my question.  It looks much clearer now.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen I have access to a lab with ~200 systems, and a few servers. All of them (even the couple of 12.04 ones, others all 14.04), without fail, have the relative symbolic link (with `..`). It looks like a bug of some sort. Perhaps you should have a new question ("Why don't I get name resolution with the normal, relative link?")

Comment: Thanks, I will try to formulate another question, based on the findings so far.